How to boot Kali Linux live system directly to text terminal?

I have a Kali Linux live system installed on a USB with encrypted persistence. Unfortunately during upgrade there were issues and GUI doesn't load. I'm trying to recover data from the encrypted persistence. How do I boot to the text terminal, so I could mount /dev/sda2 and recover data?

Can you not simply run an alternative live system, plug in your current, problematic drive, and copy the data to a new place. Effectively, install a new Kali system on a new drive (without "upgrading"), create new persistent encrypted storage, plug in your problematic drive, enter the password for the encrypted spaced, and copy to the new space. Note ... I am a novice so I might be suggesting something impossible ... but it does look much like the same problem one can encounter upgrading a Tails live system with encrypted persistence.
